# Is the question wrong? Approximate binomial with normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, approximation, binomial-distribution

The results of the exam are a normal approximation to the binomial distribution. The maximum exam score is 100 points with µ = 60 and ơ = 7.

a) When X is a binomial random variable that can be approximated by the normal distribution, calculate the probability that a student scores between 80 and 90 points?

Is this question wrong? If X is a binomial random variable and X is the score, then X can't be a binomial random variable, because the score has more than two possible results. Therefore, this question is wrong.

Comment: The possible values of a binomial random variable with parameters $n$ and $p$ are all the integers $0$ to $n$.  You may have confused "binomial" with "Bernoulli".

Comment: How many students have attended the exam? I my view this information is missing. Additionally it should be the **average** student score in the question.

Comment: @callculus Not necessarily: the way I read the question is that you have $n=100$ possible points, and you get each point with some probability $p$.

Comment: @ClementC. The problem is that question is not well worded. But is posssible that your interpretation is right. Let´s see if the OP gives us a reply.

Comment: @callculus. The question doesn't provide more information.

Comment: @callculus In any case, that's one step further down the road -- the OP's question is more fundamental, as it hints at a misunderstanding of what a Binomial distribution is to begin with (conflating it with a Bernoulli).

Comment: @Pansen1515 Did the answers clear your doubts?

Answer (score 1):

**No**, the question is not "wrong" — the point you make reveals a confusion on your part about what a Binomial random variable is.

---

A Binomial random variable with parameters $n\geq 1$ and $p\in[0,1]$ takes values in $\{0,1,2,\dots, n\}$. It is the sum of $n$ independent *Bernoulli* random variables, each with parameter $p$.

**In short:** [Bernoulli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution): two possible outcomes, $0$ and $1$. [Binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution): $n+1$ possible outcomes (where $n$ is the parameter), $0,1,2,\dots,n$.

Answer (score 1):

The wording is awkward, but I think there are two issues worth exploring.

First, if $X \stackrel{aprx}{\sim} \mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 60, \sigma = 7),$
then find $P(80 \le X \le 90) = P(79.5 < X < 90.5),$ which can be
evaluated by standardizing and using printed standard normal CDF tables 
or by statistical software as as very
nearly $0.0005.$ In R statistical software on gets:

```
diff(pnorm(c(79.95, 80.5), 60, 7))
## 0.0004833435
```

*Note:* There are  negligible probabilities that this normal distribution
takes 'prohibited' values above 100 or below 0, but it is customary to
ignore them.

Second, one can ask, "What binomial distribution might be approximated by 
$\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 60, \sigma = 7)\,?$"
From $\mu = np = 60$ and $\sigma = np(1-p) = 50 \approx 7^2,$ one can
deduce that $n = 360$ and $p = 1/6.$ So perhaps the exam has
$n = 360$ questions with a probability $p \approx 1/6$ that any one of
them is answered correctly.

If $Y \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n = 360, p = 1/6),$ then the exact
value $P(80 \le Y \le 90) = P(Y \le 90) - P(Y \le 79) \approx 0.0013$
can be found using software:

```
diff(pbinom(c(79,80), 360, 1/6))
## 0.001253314
```

The absolute error of the various approximations is small, but the relative
error is large for the probability involved in this problem, which is far into the right tail. Perhaps the 'convenient approximation' $50 \approx 7^2$ (used to get round numbers)
should be improved a bit.

The figure below shows that $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 60, \sigma = 7)$ and
$\mathsf{Binom}(n = 360, p = 1/6)$ are a "pretty good" match.

[image]

Comment: That's useful for the exercise, but as far as I can tell that does nothing to address the actual misunderstanding of the OP regarding what a Binomial r.v. *is*: "If X is a binomial random variable and X is the score, then X can't be a binomial random variable, because the score has more than two possible results. Therefore, this question is wrong."

Comment: @ClementC. No argument with that. (+1) But sometimes it seems worthwhile to try to untangle the assigned question from the student's incorrect impression of it.

Comment: I agree. (And it'll be useful for future readers) -- just mentioning that the key confusion of the original poster is somewhat simpler.